# Vue.js filtering list with multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, filter, vue.js

I'm trying to work out how you can filter a v-for list using checkbox model array where you have multiple checkboxes ticked. Other examples I have found all do the same as my example here - just filter one checkbox at a time. Here is a simple demo of what I have so far - https://jsbin.com/fuzuzucike/1/edit?html,js,console,output as you can checkboxes 1-3 and a list of names.

If you click 1 it filters the name with id1 but then when you click 2 (with 1 still selected) no names appear. I would want names with ids 1 and 2 to show in this case. Am I missing something simple here or is it a case of having to create a custom filter to handle this functionality?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters are deprecated, use computed properties:
https://jsbin.com/jofediqifi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: That's fantastic thank you! I'd never thought of it that way but it makes total sense.